# How to achieve SEO for XHTML pages which load data in DOM using a JQuery-AJAX service calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, xhtml, seo

I have a simple website (5-8 XHTML pages and a payment gateway to be done) with about 1500 products having a fix SKU/product code.

sample URL for the query: **http://www.domainname.com/product-detail.html?20001-1P16AX** and 
I'am pulling data via a **JQuery/AJAX service calls** and pushing it to to the DOM.

The meta tags, (data in bold italics) i want to populate via **service calls** as under

- <meta name="description" content="***20001-1P16AX,20001 - 1P 16AX 1-way switch grey,EIKON,175***" />
- <meta name="keywords" content="***20001-1P16AX,20001,switch,grey,EIKON,175,SWITCH,GREY***"/>

---

My query is ...

- Can we load SEO data in meta tahgs via **JQuery/AJAX service calls**?
- Whether Google or other popular search engines cache this dynamic data and redirect to the **EXACT** product page when searched?
- Is there any better way to achieve SEO/perform search for the above said scenario?

I would be very happy to hear from all you experts, please suggest.

Thanks
NBaua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load any data with Ajax call. For example, [this site](http://bbc-programmes.appspot.com/) changes the title of all pages (it could be a meta tag too) with JavaScript and Google indexes them [correctly](https://www.google.fr/search?q=site%3Abbc-programmes.appspot.com).
This site uses the "escaped URL fragments" method to be indexed.

Comment: You rock man!, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks You've made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Generally google or other crawl engines won't execute your js code and so they don't load your meta tags. But still there are ways to make your site seo friendly.

There are two ways I know. One is Hijax (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijax) and other is the html snapshot method using 'escaped url fragments' or some other method.

In my opinion, hijax is more cleaner. In this method, you just have to differentiate between browser requesting your page and crawler requesting your page. I don't know how you are triggering your ajax page changing. Information about that would be more helpful. You just have to display all the page contents including meta data without worrying about appearance or user experience from the server side only when requesting from crawler where no JavaScript would get executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have the following sequence at my end, hope this helps you understand further.....

The page I am loading data is a plain XHTML document,
The data including the meta tag data is to be fetched via a service
need to make it SEO friendly for all 1559 products.

Comment: Marked as Answer, Thanks, I am not sure how far this will take me, however looks very promising at this stage.

Comment: I just need to know the ajax content loaded whether with clicks or just url change events. that would be helpful

Comment: The AJAX is loaded with the JQuery Service calls in the page load events most of the times and YES we do refer to the querystring values to get the dynamic content every time. Do You Want me to Post Some Example by opening a another question with more specific example?

Comment: Use the method described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705532/php-ajax-and-normal-page-difference?answertab=active#tab-top) to differentiate between ajax request and normal request .Then output your meta and body content according to url parameters only if its normal get requests